# How do I restore dead Kafka brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I had a Kafka cluster with three brokers.

I killed two of them by mistake.

I restarted them with the same `server.properties` config files that was used in running them the first time, but it is not functioning correctly.

By this I mean when I run `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic <topic_name> --from-beginning`, it prints nothing, although when I replace the localhost with the address of broker server that had not been killed in `--zookeeper localhost:2181`, it has all the messages.

It seems like the two restarted Kafka brokers are not finding which cluster they should belong.

How can I fix this?

Also, how do brokers in a cluster recognize each other's address? By `zookeeper.connect` field in `server.properties` file?

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: I'm using Kafka 0.8.2.2

Comment: Okay, A couple more questions:

1) --zookeeper localhost:2181 is used to tell the consumer where the zookeeper is, not the brokers. Are you running your ZK nodes on the same hosts as the brokers?

2) What does the output of this look like? (This script is in the bin dir)
bash kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <zookeeper_host:port> --topic <topic_name> --describe

Comment: Broker servers listens on port 9092. Also,  `$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic metric.topic` gives `Topic:metric.topic PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: metric.topic Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1 `

Comment: Oh sorry, that was yesterday's output. Now it gives `Topic:metric.topic PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: metric.topic Partition: 0 Leader: -1 Replicas: 1 Isr:`

Comment: Since you have the topic set up with Replication 1 all of your data for that topic is sitting on a single broker. (There is no benefit to running a 3 node cluster if you are using replication 1 and only using a single partition) 

What does your ZK cluster look like? Are you running a ZK node on each broker? 

Please paste the server.properties and zookeeper.properties files for all of your cluster.